# Mongoose partial field search without RegEx

Tags: search, mongoose

Let's say I have this schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {type: String},
   // other fields
}, { collation: { locale: "en_US", strength: 1 } });
```

I use collation so that the search is case-insensitive

Then let's say I have a document with name "Dave"

```
{
   name: "Dave",
   // other fields
}
```

then, I search for it but without writing the whole word

```
var userList = {
   .find({name: "da"})
   .exec();
}
```

How can I make this work without using a regex expression? Which are quite slow. I have tried doing an index and then searching with the $text method but I don't know how to make it so that it searches only a specific field within the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using REGEX is your best solution. What you are trying to do is literally what regex is designed for. Yeah it's slow, but any other option you try to implement will probably be slower.

Creating a text index, and using the `$text` is only designed to match full words so you cannot use this method.

If you are truly desperate, and really don't want to use regex you can try something else... Try creating and storing an object, with each possible substring in the document. Object lookup is O(1) time, which means it will be faster, but the tradeoff is you are storing an absurd amount of data in the database. If this is ok with you, then give 'er a try.

Let's use `Dave` for example. The object you store could look something like this:

```
{
  "d": 1,
  "da": 1,
  "dav": 1,
  "dave"" 1
}
```

We can store this object in a field called `substrings`. Then when we do the database lookup, it's as simple as:

`User.find({ 'substrings.da': { $exists: true }})`

But please consider using regex... It's so much simpler, so much cleaner and it's designed for exactly what you want.